# Logback doesn't write to log file if the file path is relative

Tags: logging, logback, rollingfileappender

i am using **logback 1.0.0** and i have inside my application on root **folder** named **logs** and it contains a log **file** named **mypp.log** and my logback.xml configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>


        <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>logs\myapp.log</File>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>logs\logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>

    </appender>


    <logger name="com.myapp">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>


    <root>
        <level value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

it logs fine to console, but it doesn't log to file, unless i change the file path to be absolute
please advise how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my misunderstanding, the log folder and file was created successfully inside the **bin folder** of **jboss**.